# How to fit inputs inside fieldset

Tags: html, css

my `<input type=text>` are longer then `<select>` tags. How do I make inputs have the same width as selects?

```css
form fieldset {
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    border: 3px solid grey;
    padding: 10px;
}
form fieldset legend {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
form label {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
form input, select {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
}
form input[type=submit] {
    font-size: 20px;
    border: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
form input:focus, select:focus {
    outline: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
form div.submit {
    width: 20%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='cs'>
  <head>
      <meta charset='UTF-8'>
      <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method='POST' action='quotation.php?a=insert'>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>My legend</legend>
        <label for='customer'>Customer: </label><br>
        <select name='customer' id='customer'>
          <option value='NULL'></option>
          <option value='1'>Cust. 1</option>
          <option value='2'>Cust. 2</option>
          <option value='3'>Cust. 3</option>
        </select><br>
        <label for='contact_person'>Contact person: </label><br>
        <select name='contact_person' id='contact_person'>
          <option value='NULL'></option>
          <option value='1'>CP 1</option>
          <option value='2'>CP 2</option>
          <option value='3'>CP 3</option>
        </select><br>
        <label for='project'>Project: </label><br>
        <input type='text' name='project' id='project'><br>
        <label for='part'>Part: </label><br>
        <input type='text' name='part' id='part'><br>
        <label for='recieved'>Recieved: </label><br>
        <input type='date' name='recieved' id='recieved'><br>
        <label for='deadline'>Deadline: </label><br>
        <input type='date' name='deadline' id='deadline'><br>
        <div class='submit'>
          <input type='submit' value='Save'>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you for any idea.

I tried to set padding of whole fieldset:

`fieldset { padding: 5px }`

This is correct with  tag but doesn't work with .
Then I tried to set: `input {margin: 5px}` but this didn't work as well. In the chrome DevTools i see that the margin is ouside of the fieldset area.

Comment: This  link is not working

Comment: Should be working now. Thank you.

Comment: Edit your question and remove the <> around the words 'input' and 'select'

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Links to jsfiddle must be accompanied by the code in the question too.  Please could you edit your question and use the snippet button to add your code otherwise it is off topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this into CSS:

```
form input, select {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Because of padding, the border overflows the box so keep the top and bottom 5px and add 0 for right and left.

```
form input, select {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 padding: 5px 0;
 border: 0;
 border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
 font-size: 16px;
 width: 100%;
 font-family: 'Poppins';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update css style.

```
form input, select{
padding: 5px 0;}
```